# TRIGGER AND COUNT to limit the Count value

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

i want to create a trigger that will

- select staffid where dateread = this months date
- to count the number of a staffID
- if the count for that staff during that month is more than 5
- a stop will be issued.

here is what i did that screws me up

I would like to know is this logically correct?
and here are my compiler log errors

This is my required outcome: 
Meter readers can only read a maximum of 5 meters in any given calendar month

My Reading Table has
StaffID
MeterID
DateRead
ReadinID (PK)

Here is the error text:

```
Error(5,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(5,27): 
PL/SQL:ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 
C:\Users\ChrisPin\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\assgn2 sat4.sql Error(5,7): 
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(5,27): 
PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Here is the trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LIMIT_5_REDINGS
      BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON reading
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    ReadingCount  INTEGER;      --# of depts for this employee
      max_read   INTEGER := 5; --max number of depts per employee.
      BEGIN
      select Reading COUNT(*) into ReadingCount
      from (select *
            from Reading
            where to_char(DateRead, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM'))  
      WHERE STAFFID = :NEW.STAFFID;

    IF :OLD.STAFFID = :NEW.STAFFID THEN
        RETURN;
     ELSE
       IF ReadingCount >= max_read THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'Employees are limited to a max of two departments.');
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: And what is your question? What is not working? Is there any errors?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, i want to know what is wrong with the sql provided above, here is the compiler error log

Error(5,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(5,27): PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Please edit your question with these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in this line

```
select Reading COUNT(*) into ReadingCount
```

should be

```
select COUNT(*) into ReadingCount
```

Comment: hi thanks now it works. how ever i have this error                      line 15
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'T31917531.LIMIT_5_REDINGS'
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.

Comment: @ChrisPin, Yes - it's your error, the one you raise when `ReadingCount >= max_read`